# What causes the glow in fusor experiments?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

In short: *Is the glow produced during nuclear fusion in a fusor the same as the glow (Cherenkov radiation) produced in nuclear fission?*

In nuclear fission Cherenkov radiation is formed by high-energy neutrons colliding with water particles, as far as I understand.

The fusor experiment is done in a near-vaccuum, is the glow that is emanated caused by high-energy neutrons colliding with the H-particles that reside in the space?

Comment: No. Just the normal glow of a non-fusing plasma as electrons and ions recombine. The fusion yield is quite low, and there is no particularly good reason for the n+p reaction to glow in the visible.

Comment: @JonCuster: dammit Jon, that should be an answer!

Comment: @JohnRennie - very well! It just seems so, well, simple. But I prefer my D-T reactions in a more direct and controlled way with ion beams.

Comment: cherenkov radiation is electrons moving faster than the local speed of light (which is slower in water) so they emit photons to reduce their energy so that it is below the local speed of light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. What you see is just the normal glow of a non-fusing plasma as electrons and ions recombine. The fusion yield is quite low, and there is no particularly good reason for the n+p reaction to glow in the visible.